# How do I create an additional non-model CharField for a DRF 3 serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my serializer:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    postType = serializers.CharField(default='posts');

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'usersVoted', 'post', 'postType')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'owner', 'postType')
```

`postType` is the additional field which I want to send to the front-end with a string value of 'posts'. I made sure that it is ReadOnly by placing it in the `read_only_fields` variable. The problem is that I am receiving an error message saying this:

```
AttributeError at /posts/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `postType` on serializer `PostSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Post` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Post' object has no attribute 'postType'.
```

Any way for me to solve this? I don't think a `SerializerMethodField` is needed because I simply just want to add the string 'posts' to the serializer so an entire function is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the answer in the DRF docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

**SerializerMethodField** This is a read-only field...It can be used to add any sort of data to the serialized representation of your object.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    days_since_joined = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def get_days_since_joined(self, obj):
        return (now() - obj.date_joined).days
```

Update: Now for your case:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    postType = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'usersVoted', 'post')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'owner')

    def get_postType():
        return "posts"
```

Comment: Hm, I was hoping I wouldn't require a method. You mention that it is a read-only field. Would I be able to use a `ReadOnlyField` to accomplish the same thing?: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield

Comment: No,  ReadOnlyField is again related to your Model class. Why do you have the problem with using SerializerMethodField? See the edited example.

Comment: how can we populate postType value dynamically based on some data passed?

Answer (score 0):

You got that exception because `read_only_fields` are supposed to be from the model while `postType` isn't a model field.

Comment: Ah okay. So what would be the way to solve the issue? Using a methodfield? No other way?

Comment: What about pushing the read_only argument to the field directly ?     postType = serializers.CharField(default='posts', read_only=True)